# Prevent Named Pipes Conflict

Tags: wcf, named-pipes

We have a .NET program that uses WCF to listen for communication from another process.  We used named pipes.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
  typeof(Something),
  new Uri[]
    {
        new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
    });
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISomething), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "Something");
host.Open();
```

The code worked great until a third party .NET program was installed.  Now the open fails with a message of "Cannot listen on pipe name 'net.pipe://localhost/' because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name."

My assumption is that the other program is already using named pipes.  Is there a workaround or can only one program on a computer use named pipes?  I get the impression from other questions that you can set a "name" for a pipe so it doens't conflict with other processes, how do you do that?

Comment: Can use Handle.exe from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) to find out what application is using currently using your named pipe.  Command "Handle.exe net.pipe:".  See [Rodney Viana's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name.aspx)

Comment: The link to Rodney Viana's post, referenced in the previous comment, is no longer valid. You can use this one: https://rodneyviana.com/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use multiple named pipes at a time. Take a look at Juval Lowy's ServiceModelEx from his book Programming WCF Services. You will see when he creates named pipes, he uses code that looks something like:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Which should avoid name conflicts.

Comment: But how does the client know the server address if it is generated on the run?

Comment: You may pass it as a parameter to the client or write it in the registry or put it in a (maybe temporary) settings file.