# WCF Named Pipe Another Endpoint Error but no other endpoints?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, named-pipes, .net-3.0

I'm using a `DuplexChannelFactory` to create a named pipe on `net.pipe://localhost/test`. However, when I run my program, I get an error: `Cannot listen on pipe name "net.pipe://localhost/" because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name.`

So I tried to see whether this was actually the case, by opening a powershell and typing in `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\)`, but there is no mention of localhost.

I then also tried to change the address `net.pipe://localhost/test` to `net.pipe://anything/test` but it still didn't work.

Finally I restarted the computer and it worked. But restarting the computer is not optimal, and I restarted it again earlier today and it broke again.

Could there be any other reason why I would get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF Named pipes operate on a different system to regular nameed pipes. When you open a regular named pipe on localhost, you will get a pipe at `\.\pipe\localhost`, but when you open a WCF pipe you will get `\.\pipe\some-guid-xxxx-xxxx`. This generated GUID is consistent for WCF named pipes of the same name, which is why it works seamlessly.  (see [Prevent Named Pipes Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118114/prevent-named-pipes-conflict))

Now, in my code, I wanted to create a named pipe on `localhost`. It didn't show up in `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\)`, because WCF uses a UUID.

The workaround I used in the end is to specify the pipe url as `net.pipe\localhost\something_specific_to_me` and have an additional `AddServiceEndpoint(...,"something_else")`, so that the final pipe could be connected to via `net.pipe\localhost\something_specific_to_me\something_else`.